# Javascript encoded in HTML not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple thing that changes the value of the paragraph based on a prompt. I have the javascript encoded into the html. But when I run it, the screen is blank. The prompt doesn't even show up. I am a beginner, so this is probably easy to solve, but could someone please help? Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Randomness!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="change"> </p>

        <script>
            var change = prompt("Enter 1 or 2");

            if (change === 1) {
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said one!";
            }

            if change === 2 {
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said two!";
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "That was not an option.";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error . Correct below if condition to make it work

```
  if (change === '2') {
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yJRQNO

To make the functionality to work, update if condition comparison to string values 1 and 2

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Randomness!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="change"> </p>

        <script>
            var change = prompt("Enter 1 or 2");
console.log(change)
            if (change === '1') {
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said one!";
            }

            else if (change === '2') {
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said two!";
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "That was not an option.";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: should be `else if`

Comment: yes @AdamBuchananSmith , thanks ...updated codepen :)

Comment: you should update answer on here as well really as yeah you fixed the syntax but if change === 1 then his output will be the end else clause all the time

Answer (score 1):

You need surround your if condition this will work below.. you should make this a`else if`as well because if the value of `change` is `1` it will always go into the last `else` clause.. (a switch statement would of been better probably) anyway here this will work.

```
   var change = prompt("Enter 1 or 2");

   if (change === '1') {
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said one!";
   }

   else if (change === '2') {
       document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said two!";
   }
   else {
       document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "That was not an option.";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about else if.

Comment: I was going to mention the need for the single quotes, you caught it before I commented :)

Comment: ha thanks.. yeah i just noticed it before i clicked off the question! @AdamBuchananSmith

Answer (score 0):

Based on my opinion there is a syntax error on the second if statement.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: P.S. Could you please rate my question +1? I am new and only have 10 reputation. If you put it up one I should have fifteen and be able to rate your answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems here.

1) `change` will be a string, not an integer
2) no parens around the second condition
3) condition should be an `else if`

Try:

```js
var change = prompt("Enter 1 or 2");

if (change === '1') {
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said one!";
} else if (change === '2') {
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "You said two!";
} else {
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "That was not an option.";
}
```

```html
<p id="change"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`change`, when prompted, is a String. You are comparing it to a Number using `===`, which checks for types, so it's not going to work.

You shoud either:

- Use `parseInt` to convert the entered String to a Number:

  `var change = parseInt( prompt("Enter 1 or 2"), 10);`
- Use `==`, which will ignore types:

  `if(change == 1)`
- Use Strings as comparisons:

  `if(change === "1")`

You're also missing parenthesis around your second condition, and you should use `else if` right there.

Comment: if the prompt is returning a string, then this `if(change === "1")` is completely acceptable.